# Incorporating vis.js into polymer-starter-kit version 1.2.3

Tags: polymer, vis.js, polymer-starter-kit

I downloaded the Intermediate - Advanced users version of polymer-starter kit version 1.2.3.  I then ran

```
bower install a-dot
```

in the polymer-starter-kit directory.

I then added

```
<script src="../bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

in app/index.html

I also added

```
<paper-material elevation="1">
    <a-dot dot="digraph {1 -> 1 -> 2; 2 -> 3; 2 -- 4; 2 -> 1 }"></a-dot>
</paper-material>
```

in the

```
<section data-route="home">
</section>
```

I do not see the graph according to what I saw at:

[a-dot webcomponents page](http://web-components.in/dot/)

Does anyone out there know what I am missing?

Thank you

Update:

I also have:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/a-dot/a-dot.html"/>
```

in elements/elements.html.

Here is the full index.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <meta name="generator" content="Polymer Starter Kit"/>
  <title>Power X Hub</title>

  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the `app/` directory -->

  <!-- Chrome for Android theme color -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2E3AA1"/>

  <!-- Web Application Manifest -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/>

  <!-- Tile color for Win8 -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF"/>

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
  <meta name="application-name" content="PSK"/>
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png"/>

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Polymer Starter Kit"/>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png"/>

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png"/>

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
  <!-- endbuild-->


  <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- Because this project uses vulcanize this should be your only html import
       in this file. All other imports should go in elements.html -->
  <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">

  <!-- For shared styles, shared-styles.html import in elements.html -->
  <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

    <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
      <!-- Drawer Scroll Header Panel -->
      <paper-scroll-header-panel drawer fixed>

        <!-- Drawer Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar id="drawerToolbar">
          <span class="menu-name">Menu</span>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <!-- Drawer Content -->
        <paper-menu attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
          <a data-route="home" href="{{baseUrl}}">
            <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
            <span>Home</span>
          </a>

          <a data-route="users" href="{{baseUrl}}users">
            <iron-icon icon="info"></iron-icon>
            <span>Users</span>
          </a>

          <a data-route="contact" href="{{baseUrl}}contact">
            <iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon>
            <span>Contact</span>
          </a>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-scroll-header-panel>

      <!-- Main Area -->
      <paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" condenses keep-condensed-header>
        <!-- Main Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall">
          <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>

          <span class="space"></span>

          <!-- Toolbar icons -->
          <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>

          <!-- Application name -->
          <div class="middle middle-container">
            <div class="app-name">Power X Hub</div>
          </div>

          <!-- Application sub title -->
          <div class="bottom bottom-container">
            <div class="bottom-title">PowerXHub is a platform that connects and links the enterprise assets like logical models, databases, services, code components and documents and creates an interwoven knowledgebase of the enterprise.</div>
          </div>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="content">
          <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
            <section data-route="home">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <my-greeting></my-greeting>

                <p class="subhead">You now have:</p>
                <my-list></my-list>

                <p>Looking for more Web App layouts? Check out our <a href="https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout-templates">layouts</a> collection. You can also <a href="http://polymerelements.github.io/app-layout-templates/">preview</a> them live.</p>
              </paper-material>

              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <p>This is another card.</p>
              </paper-material>

              <a-dot dot="digraph {1 -> 1 -> 2; 2 -> 3; 2 -- 4; 2 -> 1 }"></a-dot>

              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h1 id="license">License</h1>
                <p>Everything in this repo is BSD style license unless otherwise specified.</p>
                <p>Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Authors. All rights reserved.</p>
                <p>Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:</p>
                <ul>
                <li>Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
                notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.</li>
                <li>Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
                copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer
                in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
                distribution.</li>
                <li>Neither the name of Google Inc. nor the names of its
                contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
                this software without specific prior written permission.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS &quot;AS IS&quot; AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.</p>
              </paper-material>
            </section>

            <section data-route="users">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2 class="page-title">Users</h2>
                <p>This is the users section</p>
                <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Addy">Addy</a><br>
                <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Rob">Rob</a><br>
                <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Chuck">Chuck</a><br>
                <a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Sam">Sam</a>
              </paper-material>
            </section>

            <section data-route="user-info">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2 class="page-title">User: {{params.name}}</h2>
                <div>This is {{params.name}}'s section</div>
              </paper-material>
            </section>

            <section data-route="contact">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2 class="page-title">Contact</h2>
                <p>This is the contact section</p>
              </paper-material>
            </section>
          </iron-pages>
        </div>
      </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </paper-drawer-panel>

    <paper-toast id="toast">
      <span class="toast-hide-button" role="button" tabindex="0" onclick="app.$.toast.hide()">Ok</span>
    </paper-toast>

    <!-- Uncomment next block to enable Service Worker support (1/2) -->
    <!--
    <paper-toast id="caching-complete"
                 duration="6000"
                 text="Caching complete! This app will work offline.">
    </paper-toast>

    <platinum-sw-register auto-register
                          clients-claim
                          skip-waiting
                          base-uri="bower_components/platinum-sw/bootstrap"
                          on-service-worker-installed="displayInstalledToast">
      <platinum-sw-cache default-cache-strategy="fastest"
                         cache-config-file="cache-config.json">
      </platinum-sw-cache>
    </platinum-sw-register>
    -->

  </template>

  <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you inport the a-dot element???

Comment: I forgot to say that I added <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/a-dot/a-dot.html"/> in elements/elements.html.

Comment: I tried putting the following:    <paper-material elevation="1">
      <script src="../bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
      <a-dot dot="digraph {1 -> 1 -> 2; 2 -> 3; 2 -- 4; 2 -> 1 }"></a-dot>
    </paper-material>

Comment: first of all check on  the devtools that it loads the a-dot, second remove the platform.js this is deprecated.
And then put the a-dot outside the paper-material to test it

Comment: Is there another way to incorporate vis.js besides using a-dot?

Comment: you can use vis.js without using custom element
http://visjs.org

Comment: I was missing style="width:400px;height:300px;" in the a-dot tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  It was working correctly, but the width and height for the a-dot was not set.

This is the solution:

```
<paper-material elevation="1">
    <a-dot style="width:100%;height:300px;" dot="digraph {1 -> 1 -> 2; 2 -> 3; 2 -- 4; 2 -> 1 }"></a-dot>
</paper-material>
```

Comment: Loren...Thanks for the example!  Looking forward to more example code.